# Extract a substring after a word to a specific word in a string

Tags: plsql

I have a string 'some words Host:   some characters.net some words' i want to extract the substring after Host: till .net for example some characters.net will be the output

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'some words Host: some characters.net some words'  from dual)
  3  select trim(substr(col,
  4                     instr(col, 'Host:') + 5,
  5                     instr(col, '.net') - instr(col, 'Host:'))
  6             ) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
-------------------
some characters.net

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly fine, how do i mark this as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't forget the REGEXP_SUBSTR() method! If the match is not found a NULL string is returned.

```
with test (col) as
  (select 'some words Host: some characters.net some words'  from dual)
select regexp_substr(col, 'Host: (.*\.net)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) result
from test;
```

If you want the original string to be returned if there is no match, use REGEXP_REPLACE():

```
with test (col) as
      (select 'some words Host: some characters.net some words'  from dual)
    select regexp_replace(col, '.*Host: (.*\.net).*', '\1') result
    from test;
```